# How to achieve different vertical alignment in table columns?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Can anyone help me to create a simple table in which the cells have the vertical alignments:

- column 1: top
- column 2: wrapped
- column 3: bottom?

I have used constructions like

`\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth} b{0.75\textwidth} b{0.1\textwidth}}`

and

`\begin{tabular}{r b{0.75\textwidth} r}`

and tested those like

`\begin{tabular}{r p{0.75\textwidth} b{0.1\textwidth}}`

In every case, the resulting vertical alignment for all of the columns is imposed by that for the middle column. I have also tried the `tabu` and `tabularx` packages without success.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth} b{0.75\textwidth} b{0.1\textwidth}}
10.& text text text text text text text text text text text text \dotfill&  10\\
11.& text text text text text text text text text text text text \dotfill&  11\\
12.& text text text text text text text text text text text text \dotfill&  12\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

What it produces:

[image: Vertical alignment dominated by middle column]

*Edit by CarLaTeX:*

What the OP actually want (see his/her comment under my answer) is something like a Table of Contents, for unspecified items in the text.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "wrapped" for the middle column? The `p`, `m`, and `b` column type all wrap their material, if needed.

Comment: OK, I don't care if the text is top- or bottom-aligned, but simply that it is wrapped, as in the printed output.

Answer (score 1):

As I suspected, you actually want another list like the Table of Contents, but with your own contents.

[`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package is what you need.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlistof{mylist}{mls}{My list}
\newcommand{\tolist}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{mylist}
{#1}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{mls}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\themylist.}#1}\par}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofmylist

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
Something I don't want to list

\tolist{Something I want to list}

\section{Another section}
Some blah blah blah

\tolist{Some long blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah I want to list}


\chapter{Another chapter}
\section{A section}
Something else I don't want to list

\tolist{Something else I want to list}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I want to achieve something like a Table of Contents, but not for Chapters, Sections, etc. Rather it is for other miscellaneous items in the text where I can place a \label and have the page number listed as described above.

Comment: @hross Please look at my rewed answer.